# USCIS processing times history

Tags: data-request, usa

The current [USCIS processing times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USCIS_processing_times) are on available on [this page](https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processTimesDisplayInit.do). Is there any dataset containing the historical USCIS processing times?